# UITable crashing when same row is selected twice

Tags: iphone, memory, uitableview

I have a UITableView, and when didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called on a row, it switches perfectly to the next view.  However, when I click the 'back' buttton and then select the same row previously selected...my app crashes.  It does not crash if I select a different row.  Here's the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDictionary *tempEventDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[arrayWithEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSLog(@"%i",tempEventDictionary);


    //push to new view and set myArray in the cardPage
    CardPageViewController *cardPageViewController = [[CardPageViewController alloc] init];
    cardPageViewController.eventDictionary = tempEventDictionary;
    [self presentModalViewController:cardPageViewController animated:YES];

    [cardPageViewController release];   
    [tempEventDictionary release];
}
```

Crashes with `“EXC_BAD_ACCESS”` message.

As you can see, I am printing the pointer address of the NSDictionary, and it seems to be looking for the same address for each individual indexPath.row.  This means that the pointer location is being released, and when I try to reasign it to a value of the same indexPath.row, the old pointer address is being searched for, yet it does not exist.  Maybe I'm totally wrong here.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of the crash?

Comment: There is no output.  Just a crash.  I think one time I saw a malloc thing when I tried to make my dictionary autorelease.

Comment: Certainly there is some output. Check the gdb console and paste the last message. Also, why are you printing your NSDictionary with the int format specifier ("%i")?

Comment: I am printing with the int format to see the pointer location.  There is no output from the crash in my console, only the values printed from my NSLogs.

Comment: Sorry, got the “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” message.

Comment: use %p to print pointers with NSLog

Comment: @JohnJ in Xcode: go to Run, then choose Debug - Breakpoints On, or press SHIFT+COMMAND+Y. When your app crashes, it should tell you where the crash is occurring, or give you more info other than “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Comment: Got it.  Should I print all of this data above?  It looks very impossible for me to read/understand.

Comment: To start debugging EXC_BAD_ACCESS, turn on NSZombieEnabled. (Google will provide tutorials.) That'll hopefully tell you what object you're over-releasing.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing obviously wrong with the code you've posted. My guess would be that you're overreleasing one of your data objects somewhere within `CardPageViewController` and then when your code tries to make a temporary dictionary from the same data again, it encounters a dealloced object within the dictionary and that's when the crash happens.

Answer (score 0):

I have a "hack" of an answer that keeps the object alive before the retain count goes all the way down with this elusive autorelease.  I initialize the dictionary, and then set it so the retain count goes to 2, and the hidden (to my eyes) autorelease doesn't crash the program.  Here is the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//---send data to cardPage

CardPageViewController *cardPageViewController = [CardPageViewController alloc];

NSDictionary *tempEventDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[arrayWithEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cardPageViewController.eventDictionary = [arrayWithEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[self presentModalViewController:cardPageViewController animated:YES];
[cardPageViewController release];
}
```

I hope this helps someone who can't find this released dictionary.

Comment: Never `alloc` without immediately `init`'ing.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a custom init that takes a dictionary and then copy the dictionary inside the your custom init for the new view controller?